# JavaScript namespaces

Tags: javascript, namespaces

Which is the best way to access a function or property from one namespace within another in JavaScript? Example:

```
var NS = {};  
NS.A = {  
    prop1: 'hello',
    prop2: 'there',
    func: function() {alert('boo');}  
};  

NS.B.C = {  

    func1: function() {
        // Here I want to access the properties and function from the namespace above
        alert( NS.A.prop1 + NS.A.prop2 ); // ?
        NS.A.func(); // ?
    }

};

NS.B.C.func1();
```

Comment: Ok, but do I have to write 100 times  NS.A for every property or function I want to access? Or should I better create a local variable pointing to NS.A? As a matter of fact, I am trying the second, but don't find it clean either.

Comment: You should read about javascript closure. Having a local variable within scoop pointing outside to NS.A will definitely be faster than referring a variable outside the scoop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, a "namespace" in JavaScript is just a **global** object where a collection of associated functions and pieces of data are stored (instead of having lots of globals, one for each function and piece of data).

The only reason your example won't work is that `NS.B` is undefined when you try to assign a `C` property to it.

Answer (score 2):

NS.B.C causes the error... something like this should work for you:

```
NS.B = {
  C: {
    func1: function() {
        // Here I want to access the properties and function from the namespace above
        alert( NS.A.prop1 + NS.A.prop2 ); // ?
        NS.A.func(); // ?
    }
  }
};
```

See http://jsbin.com/eweta5/2 for example.